# How to test business logic in method?

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have such method in my service layer:

```
public Long calculateItemsCostInShoppingCart(Long shoppingCartId) {
    List<Item> items = shoppingCartRepository.findAllItems(shoppingCartId);
    Long cost = 0L;
    for (Item item : items) {
        cost += item.getPrice();
    }
    return cost;
}
```

And I need to test calculation of summary cost of all items in list. I was thought about mockito, but it didn't work out cause mockito just create stubs, I need real entrance data and result based on them. How can do it?

Comment: *"I need real entrance data and result based on them"* - no you don't. Mock  `shoppingCartRepository`, let it return a sample list of `Item`s when calling `findAllItems` and then assert that the returned value matches the one you expect.

Comment: You just need a list of item that are able to return a price so you can sum everything, you can for example provide the reference to the shoppingCartRepository in the constructor of your class. Let spring autowire it for prod, and call it explicitely from the unit test with an implementation of your own that return a list of items. @davixdxx response show a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//  create mock
ShoppingRepository mock = mock(ShoppingRepository.class);

// define return value for method findAllItems()
when(mock.findAllItems()).thenReturn(listOf(...));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how you can test it with Mockito:

```
public class SomeCalculatorTest {

    @Mock
    private ShoppingCartRepository shoppingCartRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private SomeCalculator someCalculator = new SomeCalculator();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testEmptyItemsList() {
        when(shoppingCartRepository.findAllItems(any())).thenReturn(new ArrayList<>());
        final Long result = someCalculator.calculateItemsCostInShoppingCart(1L);
        assertThat(result, is(0L));
    }

    @Test
    public void testOneItemInList() {
        when(shoppingCartRepository.findAllItems(any())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new ItemImpl(25L)));
        final Long result = someCalculator.calculateItemsCostInShoppingCart(1L);
        assertThat(result, is(25L));
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwoItemInList() {
        when(shoppingCartRepository.findAllItems(any())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new ItemImpl(25L), new ItemImpl(12L)));
        final Long result = someCalculator.calculateItemsCostInShoppingCart(1L);
        assertThat(result, is(37L));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are developing a Java web application which runs on a application server another option might be to use Arquillian (http://arquillian.org/). In a nutshell, Arquillian is a framework which allows you to test you logic in environment it will run. But it might be some work to integrate Arquillian into your project. We are using Arquillian in several projects and it works well so far. Even the Persistence module which is an Alpha version works well.

Answer (score 0):

> And I need to test calculation of summary cost of all items in list.

In this case, you have to isolate the `shoppingCartRepository` dependency that doesn't perform any calculation.

> I need real entrance data and result based on them. How can do it?

It describes an integration test. In this case, don't use Mockito.

**To unit test :**

You have to mock the dependency and you also need a way to set it in the instance of the class under test.
A constructor is often a fine way (let calling the class under test `MyService`):

```
public MyService(ShoppingCartRepository shoppingCartRepository){
   this.shoppingCartRepository = shoppingCartRepository;
}
```

Then, in the test you should mock `ShoppingCartRepository`, record a behavior for `findAllItems()` and pass the mock in the constructor of MyService.

```
@Mock
private ShoppingCartRepository shoppingCartRepositoryMock;

@Test
public void calculateItemsCostInShoppingCart(){

   Long cartId = Long.valueOf(123);   

   // set the dependency
   MyService myService = new MyService(shoppingCartRepositoryMock);

   // create the mock
   Mockito.when(shoppingCartRepositoryMock.findAllItems(cartId))
          .thenReturn(createMockedItems());

   //action
   Long actualCost = myService.calculateItemsCostInShoppingCart(cartId);

   // assertion
   Assert.assertEquals(expectedCost, actualCost);
}

 private List<Item> createMockedItems() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rest assured library for test
get Rest assured response Object, and call method for method object of list.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void init() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost";
    RestAssured.port = 8080;
}
@Test
public void testUserRegistration() {
    Response response = 
            RestAssured
            .given()
            .get(URL_LOGIN)
            .then()
            .assertThat()
            .statusCode(200);

    Assert.assertThat(200, Matchers.is(200));
    Assert.assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), Matchers.is(200));
}
```